# Under What Conditions can req.connection.remoteAddress be Blank (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app running under Node.js v6.9.4, serving both via HTTP and HTTPS.

I've noticed a few times that requests coming in have had blank remoteAddress data.

Under what conditions can a request have no / blank remoteAddress?

Comment: Turns out this is the wrong question. My issue wasn't that remoteAddress was undefined (I already had code in place to handle proxies, forwarded headers etc) but that req.connection was undefined. I've created a new question. However since the question was answered correctly, I will mark the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remote address is blank when behind a proxy

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1210

you can use

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || (req.connection && req.connection.remoteAddress) || ''
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Express behind proxies

> Although the app will not fail to run if the application variable trust proxy is not set, it will incorrectly register the proxy’s IP address as the client IP address unless trust proxy is configured.

The alternative solution of getting the IP address is provided by @trushar-gupta

You can also learn more about *Express proxies*
 [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)